# Test error 404 with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

The purpose of my test it's to check that a function returns error 404, or to be more accurate, function creates call to server ( i am using guzzle) and i expect the server to return error 404, but  i can't find any `@expectedException` which make sense cause it's an ERROR, but does anyone know how can i test this case with phpunit ??? thx

in case it might help, this is how the function looks like (last attempt) :

```
public function testApi_deleteExecuted()
  {
     $path = '/adserver/src/public/api/rule/288';
     $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://10.0.0.38']);
     $response = $client->get($path);
     $data = json_decode($response->getBody());
     $code = $response->getStatusCode();

     $this->assertEquals($code, 404);

  }
```

Comment: does your function not work? looks like it should do

Answer (score 7):

so apparently guzzle has the answer, `http_errors`.

function didn't  work before but it works now:

```
  public function testApiRule_deleteExecuted()
  {
     $path = '/adserver/src/public/api/rule/288';
     $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://10.0.0.38']);
     $response = $client->get($path, ['http_errors' => false]);
     $err = $response->getStatusCode();

     $this->assertEquals($err, 404);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this in Laravel:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tests\TestCase;

class Page404Test extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function page_status_is_404()
    {
        $response = $this->get('yahoo/oops')
            ->assertSee('Error 404. No such page.');

        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
    }
}
```